# pytest multiple command-line skip options

Tags: python, pytest

I have different suites of tests.

There are normal tests, there are slow tests, and there are backend tests **(and arbitrarily more "special" tests that may need to be skipped unless specified).**

I would like to always skip slow and backend tests, unless `--run-slow` and/or `--run-backend` CLI options are passed.

If only `--run-slow` is passed, I will run all normal tests **plus** "slow" tests (eg those tests marked `@pytest.mark.slow`). Same thing for `--run-backend`; and if both CLI options are passed then run all normal tests + slow tests + backend tests.

I followed the pytest [Control skipping of tests according to command line option pattern](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option) from the docs, but find myself not yet knowledgeable enough of pytest to extend it to having *multiple* skip CLI options.

Can anyone help me out?

Reference code snippet:

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--run-slow",    action="store_true", default=False, help="run slow tests")
    parser.addoption("--run-backend", action="store_true", default=False, help="run backend tests")


def pytest_configure(config):
    config.addinivalue_line("markers", "slow: mark test to run slow")
    config.addinivalue_line("markers", "backend: mark test as backend")


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    if config.getoption("--run-slow") or config.getoption("--run-backend"): # <-- this line logic is bad!
        return
    skip = pytest.mark.skip(reason="need '--run-*' option to run")
    for item in items:
        if "slow" in item.keywords or "backend" in item.keywords:
            item.add_marker(skip)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, you can use `"not slow and not backend"` or `"not (slow or backend)"` to skip tests with both markers. You may use that in combination with your options, or instead of the options.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking for the logic in `pytest_collection_modifyitems`. You could just change your code to something like:

*conftest.py*

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    run_slow = config.getoption("--run-slow")
    run_backend = config.getoption("--run-backend")
    skip = pytest.mark.skip(reason="need '--run-*' option to run")
    for item in items:
        if (not run_slow and "slow" in item.keywords or 
            not run_backend and "backend" in item.keywords):
            item.add_marker(skip)
```

This would skip all tests marked as `slow` or `backend` by default. If adding the command line options `--run-slow` and/or `--run-backend`, the respective tests would not be skipped.

Another option (as mentioned in the comments) would be filtering by markers. In this case, instead of adding your own command line options, you could just [filter tests by markers](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/markers.html#marking-test-functions-and-selecting-them-for-a-run), e.g. use `pytest -m "not (slow or backend)"` to not run tests with these markers, and use `pytest -m "not slow"` and `pytest -m "not backend"` if you want to skip tests only for one marker. In this case you don't have to implement `pytest_collection_modifyitems`, but the default behavior would be to run all tests.

Comment: Thank you for sharing a fix here! I ended up using `pytest -m 'not (slow or backend)'` based on your comments. This solution works, but I'm not as satisfied having to explicitly exclude tests that I'd like to be implicitly skipped unless flagged to run. As in, I'd ideally like to `pytest tests/` to run all not slow or backend, and only run the slow or backend tests when explicitly flagged to run, rather than the other way around.
Haven't found a clean way to do this yet, but still learning!

Comment: I adapted the answer to be more clear. The marker filtering option is just a second possibility to do this, but implementing `pytest_collection_modifyitems` as shown should do exactly what you want.